# Oracle Database - DBA Role reporting and removal

Tags: oracle, database-administration

We have a number of Oracle databases which are connected to applications, however there are a number of accounts where it is not documented whether they are still in use which have the dba role. Is there a way to identify whether an Oracle DBA account is still being used to access the Oracle Tables, to help with removing unused accounts with the dba role.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way would be to  check the `LAST_LOGIN` date of each DBA from the view [DBA_USERS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/refrn/DBA_USERS.html)

```
select username, last_login
from   dba_users
where  username not in ('SYS', 'SYSTEM')
order by last_login
```

If you want to get more in details and see last DBA operations on specific tables, it requires to have audit activated on the databases

Answer (score 0):

```
select grantee, u.last_login, granted_role
from dba_role_privs p, dba_users u
WHERE p.granted_role='DBA'
AND u.username = p.grantee
AND u.username NOT IN ('SYS', 'SYSTEM')
```